# adding search field to view specific report in point of sale

Tags: php, sql

I am developing point of sale. I have a profit report module in which i can display profit report by inputting date.Now i also want to add search field which can search report by specific supplier of product and date.Following code only displays profit by date,help me adding search by supplier_id and date in this query?

Database madd
Table structure for table stock_details
Column  Type    Null    Default Links to    Comments
id  int(10) No
stock_id    varchar(120)    No
stock_name  varchar(120)    No
stock_quatity   int(11) No
supplier_id varchar(250)    No
company_price   decimal(10,2)   No
selling_price   decimal(10,2)   No
category    varchar(120)    No
date    timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
expire_date datetime    No
uom varchar(120)    No

Table structure for table stock_sales
Column  Type    Null    Default Links to    Comments
id  int(10) No
transactionid   varchar(250)    No
stock_name  varchar(200)    No
category    varchar(120)    No
supplier_name   varchar(200)    No
selling_price   decimal(10,2)   No
quantity    decimal(10,2)   No
amount  decimal(10,2)   No
date    date    No
username    varchar(120)    No
customer_id varchar(120)    No
subtotal    decimal(10,2)   No
payment decimal(10,2)   No
balance decimal(10,2)   No
discount    decimal(10,0)   No
tax decimal(10,0)   No
tax_dis varchar(100)    No
dis_amount  decimal(10,0)   No
grand_total decimal(10,0)   No
due date    No
mode    varchar(250)    No
description varchar(500)    No
count1  int(11) No
billnumber  varchar(120)    No

```css
//detail_profit_report.php
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stock_sales where date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' ");

                    
                                    while ($line = $db->fetchNextObject($result)) {
                                        ?>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php $mysqldate = $line->date;
                                                $phpdate = strtotime($mysqldate);
                                                $phpdate = date("d/m/Y", $phpdate);
                                                echo $phpdate; ?></td>

                                            <td><?php echo $line->transactionid; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $line->stock_name; ?></td>
                                            <td>


<?php

$nam=$line->stock_name;
$t="select supplier_id from stock_details where stock_name='$nam'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db->connection, $t);
 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo $row2['supplier_id'];
}


?>

</td>
                                            
 <td><?php echo $line->quantity; ?></td>
                                                                                       
<td>

<?php

$nam=$line->stock_name;
$t="select * from stock_details where stock_name='$nam'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db->connection, $t);
//$profit=0;
 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
$profit=$profit+(($row2['selling_price']-$row2['company_price'])*$line->quantity);
echo (($row2['selling_price']-$row2['company_price'])*$line->quantity);

}


?>

</td>
                                            
                                        </tr>
```

```css
//view_report.php
function detail_profit_report_fn() {
            window.open("detail_profit_report.php?from_detail_profit_date=" + $('#from_detail_profit_date').val() + "&to_detail_profit_date=" + $('#to_detail_profit_date').val(), "myNewWinsr", "width=620,height=800,toolbar=0,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,scrollbars=yes");

        }
<form action="detail_profit_report.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" name="detail_profit_report"
                                  id="detail_profit_report" target="myNewWinsr">
                                <tr>

                                    <td><strong>Detail Profit </strong></td>
                                    <td>From</td>
                                    <td><input name="from_detail_profit_date" type="text" id="from_detail_profit_date"
                                               style="width:80px;"></td>
                                    <td>To</td>
                                    <td><input name="to_detail_profit_date" type="text" id="to_detail_profit_date" style="width:80px;">
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input name="submit" type="button" value="Show" onClick='detail_profit_report_fn();'>
                                    </td>
                                   <td> <input name="searchtxt" type="text" class="round my_text_box" placeholder="Search">
                           
</td>
                                </tr>

                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use previous query for this with little modification

```
    SELECT * FROM stock_sales where date BETWEEN('$fromdate' AND '$todate') AND supplier_id='$supplier_id' ;
```

Comment: but How to link search text field with the query and one more thing that supplier_id is not in stock_sales.It is in stock_details table.

Comment: search key should be in the form tag and will be available after submission of the server side.
For the updated query please write the structure of your database.

Comment: add supplier_id as a foreign key in table stock_sales.  is it your transaction  table??

Comment: So that you will be able to access as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try this query as defined requirements

```
select stock_sales.id,stock_sales.transactionid,stock_sales.stock_name,
stock_sales.catgory,stock_sales.supplier_name,
stock_sales.selling_price,stock_sales.quantity,stock_sales.amount
,stock_sales.date,stock_sales.username,stock_sales.customer_id,
stock_sales.subtoal,stock_sales.payment,stock_sales.balance,
,stock_sales.discount,stock_sales.tax,stock_sales.tax_dis,stock_sales.dis_amount
,stock_sales.grand_total,stock_sales.due,stock_sales.mode,
stock_sales.description,stock_sales.count1,stock_sales.billnumber from stock_sales, stock_details where stock_details.stock_name like skock_details.stock_name
and date between ____________
and supplier_id = '$supplier_id'
```